# Inconsistent vertical spacing beetwen multiple tcolorbox environment

Tags: tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

I am using a template to create an E-pub from this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-template-for-amazon-kdp-leanpub-and-google-play-e-book-and-pdf-2023/ymygsdrsyvsq)

In this template, some environments are defined using tcolorbox, but I have found that the vertical space is inconsistent when using multiple tcolorbox in a row. See my pictures as an example, please. It looks like it is dependent on if the page is even or odd.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how a work-around for this?

Comment: This is not really inconsistent spacing, let alone related to `tcolorbox`. You'd get the same result with `\fbox`es. LaTeX tries to allocate equal space between the boxes, and there is simply more space on the first page than on the second. However, `tcolorbox` has a possible fix: you can make your boxes `breakable`, such that they can be distributed over the pages more evenly.

Comment: The document class you use may specified `\flushbottom`. You may try out `\raggedbottom`.